# What does Google mean by "user" in Maps Time Zone API quota?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

Looking at the Time Zone API quota limit option that says:

> "Requests per 100 seconds per user"

Was trying to find a clear definition of **user** but to no avail.

My intuitive guess it's an IP address... yet would like to avoid  unpleasant surprises.

Would be good to know what does **user** mean exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: Good luck with that. My company had (and will last a few more months) the 10K anual premium plan. It mentioned a quota of X units a day, in which they didn't count the page reloads only, but the tiles you loaded too when zooming or panning. They couldn't respond what exactly is a unit or how many of what amount for a unit... and I'm supposed to have premium support. Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a confusion that comes from the fact that Google Maps APIs share the same developer console with Google Cloud Platform. The "Requests per 100 seconds per user" make sense in Google Cloud Platform, but I don't think they are really supported in Google Maps APIs.

If we check the documentation of Google Cloud Platform we will see the following explanation

> To prevent individual users from using up your API quota, limit the number of requests per second per user for an API. Each API includes a default per-user limit, but you can modify that value as described in the previous section.
>
> Individual users are identified by a unique string; if you're creating a server-side application (where the calling code is hosted on a server that you own) that makes requests on behalf of users, your requests must include the quotaUser parameter, as described below.
>
> To identify a user, use the `quotaUser=userID` parameter. This value is for short term quota enforcement only, so you don't need to use a real user ID. You can choose any arbitrary string under forty characters long that uniquely identifies a user.
>
> The `quotaUser` parameter is only used for capping requests per user per second. If you **don't send the quotaUser parameter, then all calls are attributed to your server machines, in which case calls can't be capped by user**.

source: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_second_per_user

As far as I know none of Google Maps APIs support a `quotaUser` parameter, so this value doesn't make sense for Google Maps web services and as mentioned in the last paragraph Google Maps web services will attribute usage to server machines. In other words to IP addresses of your backend servers.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Following your logic, if all API calls come from users' browsers (meaning different IP for each user), then each user call will be identified by their IP address and therefore user "equals" IP address. Would that be a correct way of thinking?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. However, you shouldn't use web services directly from users' browsers. They are meant to be used on backend servers. For client side you can use corresponding services of Google Maps JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/services. Google Maps JavaScript API has its own per user sessions internal control.

Comment: When I tried just now to adjust the "Requests per minute per user" for geocode api, the console returned: "Error while updating the quota limit."